# How to remove items from the Android file picker drawer?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider, android-storage

Is there a way to remove items like "Downloads", "Pictures" or "Videos" sections from the android file picker?
I know that Google Drive for example can be removed using:

```java
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
```

But how can you remove the others? I'm trying it on a Samsung device, reading through some posts I found out that there might be vendor-related configurations that you have to specify for the intent. Mine looks like this:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
intent.setType("*/*");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to specify the MIME type?

Try changing this

```
intent.setType("*/*");
```

To this

```
intent.setType("image/*");
```

In this case you won't see videos and audio.
Change the MIME type according to what you need.